# How to get google sheet column values by active range selection?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below  is the sample function which I tried. How do I achieve this loop through current active selection in google sheet and its values in an array.

```
function awe(){
  var selected1 = sheetname.getActiveRange()
var values = selected1.getValue()
}
```

I am getting only value i.e in first cell in google sheet instead of the range which I selected. I want the values of all current active selected range in an array.

I want only the user selected range values only to array in google app script to process.

Answer (score 0):

#### Displaying Selected Data

```
function awe() {
  const vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea cols="50" rows="15">${JSON.stringify(vs)}</textarea>`), "Selected Data");
}
```

Selected Data Sample:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| 2 | 3 | 16 | 19 | 5 | 18 | 11 | 13 | 15 | 8 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 6 | 11 | 11 | 1 | 0 | 11 | 17 | 6 |
| 4 | 14 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 12 | 17 | 5 | 14 | 7 | 6 |
| 5 | 8 | 19 | 6 | 8 | 3 | 3 | 19 | 13 | 4 | 18 |

Dialog:

[image]

Comment: I tried it's working but above is not working when i send values to front end side bar and attach to HTML div instead of generating ui from code.gs